# Minecraft control for eating

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What key will let me eat?!  My food bar is down low, and I'm not regenerating health.  I also need to know which button to press to hand bones to wolves, or fish to kitties.

It used to be the right-click button, but I'm not getting that option.

Comment: It's still right click for all those things.

Comment: right click does need to be held down, not just tapped, to eat food. You should see the pork chop (in this case) move towards the middle of the screen and hear a "munching" noise.

Comment: @tombull89 You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 26):

While you hold the food in your hand, you must hold down the right mouse button until the food is gone. This takes somewhat between 1-2 seconds, and an eating noise will be played for the duration.

Edit: Right click at a dog to give it a bone if you have one in your hand, same with cats, just use a raw fish instead of bones.

Note: it will almost always take more than one bone/raw fish to tame an animal.

Answer (score 3):

You right click to eat. You need to hold down the right mouse button until the food disappears.
*Note:* When your hunger bar is almost full, your health will regenerate.

For feeding animals it is right click as well.
*Note:* It may take more than one bone or fish (wolves or ocelots) to befriend them.

Answer (score 0):

If holding right click doesnt work check your controls and reset to default
But to eat you must hold the right click button 
For pets click right click